# List all Safes and their balance for an EOA address

Tags: gnosis-safe

We're building a mobile app that will help users manage all their Safes. I'm investigating the proper way to do it.

So far I found out about safe-global's `safe-core-sdk`, `safe-gateway-typescript-sdk`, and `safe-client-gateway` SKDs. Then there are the APIs on `https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/backend/available-services`.

The SDK (safe-core-sdk) seems to use the API on `safe-client.safe.global`.

It appears for our use case, using the API directly instead of relying on the SDKs makes more sense because we could integrate with our current data layer and keep it consistent.

Documentation for the API seems scarce, so I'm not sure if using the API directly might  incur later in request-rate limitations or similar, or if this endpoints can be thrusted to be maintained at the same addresses.

So question is, are we fine working with the APIs directly, or are the wrapper SDKs the right way to interact with the API?

I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our team builds with Safe APIs directly in combination with usage of their SDKs. My thoughts are that it's fine to use the Safe APIs directly. With the understanding that they may not be as well documented and they may still change overtime. So far for us, the domains did get updated once while we were using them, but the old domains continued to work for long enough for us to cross over. Also we occasionally do hit rate limits, but that's not been a major issue for us.

Disclaimer: I don't work at Safe.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your feedback. We'll do the same - and if necessary spin our own instance of safe-global/safe-transaction-service.

Answer (score 0):

From the readme of the gateway SDK:

> Usage policy
> NB: Safe Client Gateway isn't meant for public use. Please do not use this SDK if you're building, e.g., a Safe App.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. There's also safe-core-sdk (https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk) I guess that's the one use then? My question regarding API usage is still valid.